# How to get NvidiaDeepstreamSDK iotedge module working on jetson nano?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge, nvidia-jetson-nano, nvidia-deepstream

I've had issues setting up the DeepstreamSdk IoTedge module on the jetson nano for the last week and I cannot get past it. I've installed IoTedge runtime and all the necessities for IoT edge to run. It runs perfectly including other modules like the simulated Temperature sensor. However when I deploy the DeepstreamSdk v-4.02 on the Jetson nano running Jetpack 4.3, it starts and runs for a couple of minutes but then fails unexpectedly and then after a bit of time starts up again and then fails again. And then Sometimes I restart the IoTedge and it will start up again and then fail. When I use the Developer extension IoTedge in VS code to see what the messages being sent up to the cloud are, I can see the temperature sensor module's messages, however none from the NvidiaDeepstream module.

I've had a look in the logs for the NvidiaDeepstream container, and it shows that it is printing out results ( messages to the cloud), but then eventually sends an error code 1. and some sort of message at the end INT8 is not supported, try INT16. All the Azure checks and connectivity and configurations are correct. It is just the deepstreamdk module that doesn't run properly.

Does anyone have any suggestions? What info should I provide to make this more clear and understandable? I am following the tutorial on the Github repository for NVIDIA Deepstream + Azure IoT Edge on a NVIDIA Jetson Nano: [Link to turorial](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/NVIDIA-Deepstream-Azure-IoT-Edge-on-a-NVIDIA-Jetson-Nano)

[Link to logs of COntainers](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lSVkP0Nh6DZqbx1FyYuRrD92D9BBM3Lg)

Comment: Could you please add the logs to the question? this way people will understand the question better

Comment: Added the links to the logs for the last hour. Hopefully that helps. I noticed that in the nvidia logs now that there was some sort of mqtt connectivity issue. Not sure how to go about solving this.

Comment: @rey The log is 6800 characters. Do you want the log added to the question or a link to the log?

Comment: @somebadhat I think if the log is that extensive the way the author did it with the link is alright.